# WebSocket connection using wasync in Android does not work

Tags: android, websocket, atmosphere

I'm using [wasync](https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync) in Android app to use WebSocket.
I got error when stating activity like following.

While testing secure websocket at http://www.websocket.org/echo.html with Chrome for Android works fine for both cases,
neither `uri("https://echo.websocket.org")` nor `uri("https://<my websocket server>")` worked.

What is wrong with my code?

My device is Nexus7(2014), Android 4.4.2.

```
    private Socket socket;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wasync_test);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                AtmosphereClient client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient(AtmosphereClient.class);
                AtmosphereRequest.AtmosphereRequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder()
                .method(Request.METHOD.GET)
                .enableProtocol(false)
                .uri("https://echo.websocket.org")
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET);
                socket = client.create()
                // on(MESSAGE, OPEN, CLOSE) are omitted
               .on(Event.ERROR, new Function<Object>() {
                   @Override
                   public void on(Object o) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "[wasync] onerror: " + o);
                   }
               });
               try {
                   socket.open(request.build());
               } catch (IOException e) {
               }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

and error I got is:

```
05-01 18:33:32.050  20891-20904/myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-267
    Process: myapp, PID: 20891
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: wss://echo.websocket.org/?X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket
            at myapp.WasyncTestActivity.run(WasyncTestActivity.java:84)
            at myapp.WasyncTestActivity.access$000(WasyncTestActivity.java:30)
            at myapp.WasyncTestActivity$1.run(WasyncTestActivity.java:41)
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: wss://echo.websocket.org/?X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket
            at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:413)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:380)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:661)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:661)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-01 18:33:32.070      653-664/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity myapp/.WasyncTestActivity
05-01 18:33:32.150  20891-20911/myapp E/WaitingActivity﹕ [wasync] onerror: java.net.ConnectException: wss://echo.websocket.org/?X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket
```

My app have permissions android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it worked for me. 
I suggest to do atmosphere related tasks in background using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Here is code for Atmosphere in android Activity

```
AtmosphereClient client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient(AtmosphereClient.class);
final RequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder()
                    .method(Request.METHOD.GET)
                    .uri(atmosphereServletPath)
                    .trackMessageLength(true)
                    /*
                     * code to set the default transport to Websocket
                     */
                    .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET)

                    /*
                     * code to set the fall-back transport to Long-Polling
                     */
                    .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING);

            /*
             * code to create the socket at server side using the created client
             */
            socket = client.create();

            /*
             * code to open the socket
             */
            socket.open(request.build());

            /*
             * code for Message handler
             */
            socket.on("message", new Function<YourObject>() {
                @Override
                public void on(final YourObject s) {
                    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        /*
                         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run() Here I've received the
                         * YourObject from the server
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            /*
                            * tasks for onMessage() method.
                            */
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

here `atmosphereServletPath` is path to your atmosphere servlet.

Comment: None of `open`ing socket before `on`, chainging `on`'s first argment to `String` nor adding `transport(Request.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING)` worked for me :-(

Comment: Please attach your server side code of Atmosphere Servlet.

Comment: If I run above code as a desktop app, it works fine. So I don't think that it's a server side problem.